# Ninject: Implement WithConstructorArgument(string name, Func<IContext,object> callback)

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a MVVM WP7 app in which I'm trying to send a value from one Page/ViewModel to the contructor of a second ViewModel. I already have Ninject set up and got this to work with a static test value using a line such as:

```
this.Bind<TaskViewModel>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("TaskID", 2690)
```

Again, that works with a static value but I need it to be a variable selected by the user. I've been told to use the overload

```
WithConstructorArgument(string name, Func<IContext,object> callback).
```

I would think that this callback would call a function on the first ViewModel and get the value.

But I have not been successful, readily admitting I am not very experienced in either Ninject or using a Func callback argument. I've tried setting up a delegate and function to get the value from the first ViewModel but that gives an error saying I'm trying to pass in a type. How exactly do I specify that argument to use a callback and am I correct to use a delegate in the first ViewModel or something else?

Comment: Are you sure that this is good idea to use dependency injection in such way? I mean to resolve component dependencies based on user input?

Comment: It was reccomended to me by someone I consider very knowledgable on Ninject, as I stated in my question, I am not. If you have a suitable solution thats fits in with MVVM I am definitely open to changing my approach.

Comment: @Waltedbn: Remo Gloor is the current active developer of the Ninject project. He is the most knowledgeable person on the topic in the world. Listen to him.

Comment: Yes, I know, Remo is the person I was actually  referring to.

Answer (score 5):

As I already said in your other post passing the argument on get is probably the better way. Therefor create a factory interface

```
public interface ITaskViewFactory
{
    TaskViewModel CreateTaskViewModel(int id);
}
```

In your bootstrapper (The assembly responsible to create everything using Ninject, which should normally be another one than where you implement everything with business value) add the implementation

```
Public class TaskViewFactory : ITaskViewFactory
{
     Private IKernel kernel;
     Public TaskViewFactory(IKernel kernel)
     {
         this.kernel = kernel;
     }

     public TaskViewModel CreateTaskViewModel(int taskId)
     {
         this.kernel.Get<ITaskViewModel>(new ConstructorArgument("TaskId", taskId);
     }
 }
```

Then inject the factory to your task selection command and call the factory whena task is selected.